# Bind properties in application.yml not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, sqlite, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my SpringBoot project I have application.yml file in src/main/resources/:

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.sqlite.JDBC
    ...
```

I want to bind the properties defined above to a Java class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public class DBConfig {

    // I wished spring-boot could automatically bind it with 'driver-class-name' in application.yml
    private String driverClassName;
    ...

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        ...
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

I have the annotation `@Configuration` and `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")`. I also have specified the correct prefix. But when I run my application I get an error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/my/webapp/config/DBConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty

The error tells `driverClassName` is an empty string, so the binding doesn't work. What am I missing? I am using an SQLite database which is not as well supported as MySQL, MariaDB, etc. in SpringBoot. So I provide a datasource bean class to bind database configurations in application.yml to the manually created bean class. Is it unnecessary?

Comment: just have a look [spring-data-jpa](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa), in my opinion you dont need to do so kind of manipulation, spring boot  provide auto-configurable dataSource connect

Comment: I am dealing with SQLite database, which is a bit special to my understanding, that is why I do this manipulation. Or, do you think even with SQLite database, I don't need to do this?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-sqlite may be it could help you

Comment: yes, just do it in a normal flow

Comment: The link @ovgu12 sent in his/her comment is also using the same way as I am using to manually create the datasource bean, so, I don't see how that helps my problem of binding properties.

Comment: [check it](https://fullstackdeveloper.guru/2020/05/01/how-to-integrate-sqlite-database-with-spring-boot/comment-page-1/#comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way for configuration properties is to keep them in the separate class and activate them using `@EnableConfigurationProperties`. You can read this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot). And you can try something as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyConfigurationProperties.class)
public class DBConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MyConfigurationProperties props;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(props.getDriverClassName());
        // ...
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

And your properties class will look like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public class MyConfigurationProperties {
    
    private String driverClassName;

    // getters ans setters are here
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is the best solution, because Spring already has its own configuration properties class that binds to the prefix `spring.datasource`.

And the second option for you is to use the Spring configuration properties:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
// ...

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DataSourceProperties.class)
public class DBConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSourceProperties props;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(props.getDriverClassName());
        // ...
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add setters for feilds in your `DBConfig` class and it will work.